# keep only lowest value per row in a Python Pandas dataset

Tags: python, pandas

In a Pandas dataset I only want to keep the lowest value per line. All other values should be deleted.
I need the original dataset intact. Just remove all values (replace by NaN) which are not the minimum.

What is the best way to do this - speed/performance wise.

I can also transpose the dataset if the operation is easier per column.

Thanks
Robert

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since the operation you are contemplating does not rely on the columns or index, it might be easier (and faster) to do this using NumPy rather than Pandas.

You can find the location (i.e. column  index) of the minimums for each row using

```
idx = np.argmin(arr, axis=1)
```

You could then make a new array filled with NaNs and copy the minimum values 
to the new array.

---

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def nan_all_but_min(df):
    arr = df.values
    idx = np.argmin(arr, axis=1)
    newarr = np.full_like(arr, np.nan, dtype='float')
    newarr[np.arange(arr.shape[0]), idx] = arr[np.arange(arr.shape[0]), idx]
    df = pd.DataFrame(newarr, columns=df.columns, index=df.index)
    return df

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,3)))
print(df)
#           0         1         2
# 0  0.542924  0.499702  0.058555
# 1  0.682663  0.162582  0.885756
# 2  0.389789  0.648591  0.513351
# 3  0.629413  0.843302  0.862828

df = nan_all_but_min(df)
print(df)
```

yields

```
          0         1         2
0       NaN       NaN  0.058555
1       NaN  0.162582       NaN
2  0.389789       NaN       NaN
3  0.629413       NaN       NaN
```

---

Here is a benchmark comparing `nan_all_but_min` vs `using_where`:

```
def using_where(df):
    return df.where(df.values == df.min(axis=1)[:,None])

In [73]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(100*100).reshape(100,100))

In [74]: %timeit using_where(df)
1000 loops, best of 3: 701 µs per loop

In [75]: %timeit nan_all_but_min(df)
10000 loops, best of 3: 105 µs per loop
```

---

Note that `using_where` and `nan_all_but_min` behave differently if a row contains the same min value more than once. `using_where` will preserve all the mins, `nan_all_but_min` will preserve only one min. For example:

```
In [76]: using_where(pd.DataFrame([(0,0,1), (1,2,1)]))
Out[76]: 
   0   1   2
0  0   0 NaN
1  1 NaN   1

In [77]: nan_all_but_min(pd.DataFrame([(0,0,1), (1,2,1)]))
Out[77]: 
   0   1   2
0  0 NaN NaN
1  1 NaN NaN
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I was not completely clear in what I need. I need the original dataset intact. Just remove all values (replace by NaN) which are not the minimum.

Comment: If I can give another +1, I would. That optimization is insane!

Comment: Works great! Thanks a lot. As I also have NaN values in the df I replaces np.argmin with np.nanargmin.

Answer (score 1):

Piggybacking off @unutbu's excellent answer, the following minor change should accommodate your modified question.

[**The where method**](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.15.0/indexing.html#the-where-method-and-masking)

```
In [26]: df2 = df.copy()

In [27]: df2
Out[27]: 
   0   1   2
0  0   1   2
1  3   4   5
2  6   7   8
3  9  10  11

In [28]: df2.where(df2.values == df2.min(axis=1)[:,None])
Out[28]: 
   0   1   2
0  0 NaN NaN
1  3 NaN NaN
2  6 NaN NaN
3  9 NaN NaN
```

Mandatory speed test.

```
In [29]: df3 = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random(100*100).reshape(100,100))

In [30]: %timeit df3.where(df3.values == df3.min(axis=1)[:,None])
1000 loops, best of 3: 723 µs per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data frame already contains NaN values, you must use numpy's [nanmin](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.nanmin.html) as follows:

```
df2.where(df2.values==np.nanmin(df2,axis=0))
```

Answer (score 0):

I just found and tried out the answer by unutbu.
I tried the .where method, but it will be deprecated soon.

```
FutureWarning: Support for multi-dimensional indexing (e.g. `obj[:, None]`) is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.  Convert to a numpy array before indexing instead.
```

However, i got this sucker working instead. However, it is a lambda function, and most likely slower...

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((4,3)))
print(df)
#           0         1         2
# 0  0.542924  0.499702  0.058555
# 1  0.682663  0.162582  0.885756
# 2  0.389789  0.648591  0.513351
# 3  0.629413  0.843302  0.862828

    mask = df.apply(lambda d:(d == df.min(axis=1)))
    print (df[mask])
```

Should yield:

```
        0         1         2
0       NaN       NaN  0.058555
1       NaN  0.162582       NaN
2  0.389789       NaN       NaN
3  0.629413       NaN       NaN
```